# Ruby regex - Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a 2-D ruby array which looks something like this :

```
(Array) - @main.each do |value| 

value[0]    value[1]   value[2]

3.0.1.2     TOTAL      Pass
3.0.1.3     TOTAL      Pass
3.4.0.1     8K         Fail
3.5.4.3     9K         Fail
3.5.0.9     TOTAL      Fail
```

I want to seperate them into 2 arrays such that first one should have all rows with 'TOTAL' and the other array should have everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow what the fields of your array are but you can use select and reject:

```
totals = @main.select{|entry| entry == "TOTAL"}
others = @main.reject{|entry| entry == "TOTAL"}
```

For whatever test you have of each element. The original @main will stay as it was and you can use totals and others to access the elements.

Comment: Do it in [one pass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15583917/1074296) with [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

Answer (score 4):

```
@main = [
  %w[3.0.1.2     TOTAL      Pass],
  %w[3.0.1.3     TOTAL      Pass],
  %w[3.4.0.1     8K         Fail],
  %w[3.5.4.3     9K         Fail],
  %w[3.5.0.9     TOTAL      Fail],
]

totals, others = @main.partition{|a| a[1] == 'TOTAL'}

# totals => [["3.0.1.2", "TOTAL", "Pass"], ["3.0.1.3", "TOTAL", "Pass"], ["3.5.0.9", "TOTAL", "Fail"]]
# others => [["3.4.0.1", "8K", "Fail"], ["3.5.4.3", "9K", "Fail"]]
```

Comment: This does partition it, but the new arrays have only the a[1] field.....I want the other fields to remain intact too.

Comment: @sagarvikani When I run it, the new arrays contain the original tuples. [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) partitions based on the block, but produces the original elements.

Comment: @sagarvikani Perhaps you could more accurately show us your input, since your question has a rather obscure representation?  I've updated this answer to demonstrate exactly how I interpreted your `@main` to be structured.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't explained well, but as a quick guess for what you want I'll recommend looking at [`Array.group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which is part of Enumerable:

```
ary = [
  %w[3.0.1.2     TOTAL      Pass],
  %w[3.0.1.3     TOTAL      Pass],
  %w[3.4.0.1     8K         Fail],
  %w[3.5.4.3     9K         Fail],
  %w[3.5.0.9     TOTAL      Fail],
]


ary.group_by{ |a| a.last }
```

Which returns a hash, with the keys being the two different values for the last element in the sub-arrays:

```
{
    "Pass" => [
        [0] [
            [0] "3.0.1.2",
            [1] "TOTAL",
            [2] "Pass"
        ],
        [1] [
            [0] "3.0.1.3",
            [1] "TOTAL",
            [2] "Pass"
        ]
    ],
    "Fail" => [
        [0] [
            [0] "3.4.0.1",
            [1] "8K",
            [2] "Fail"
        ],
        [1] [
            [0] "3.5.4.3",
            [1] "9K",
            [2] "Fail"
        ],
        [2] [
            [0] "3.5.0.9",
            [1] "TOTAL",
            [2] "Fail"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Accessing one or the other is easy:

```
ary.group_by{ |a| a.last }['Pass']
[
    [0] [
        [0] "3.0.1.2",
        [1] "TOTAL",
        [2] "Pass"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "3.0.1.3",
        [1] "TOTAL",
        [2] "Pass"
    ]
]
```

Or:

```
ary.group_by{ |a| a.last }['Fail']
[
    [0] [
        [0] "3.4.0.1",
        [1] "8K",
        [2] "Fail"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "3.5.4.3",
        [1] "9K",
        [2] "Fail"
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] "3.5.0.9",
        [1] "TOTAL",
        [2] "Fail"
    ]
]
```